# Google Maps Android API v2 MapView animation failure

Tags: android, android-mapview, google-maps-android-api-2

My app displays search results in a ListView and MapView within a ViewFlipper. The user can toggle between them with a 3D flip animation.

Today I updated to highly anticipated Google Maps Android API v2 and everything went smoothly, except my animation. I'm applying an android.view.animation.Animation to the view very similar to the 3d flip animation described [here](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html). Now the width is transformed, so the view of the Map expands from the center, but there is no skewed transformation, it is just flat.

Again, this worked with com.google.android.maps.MapView, but not the new version, com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=animation&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal&groupby=&sort=&id=4782) the problem is that gmaps relies on SurfaceView to draw. And SurfaceView [doesn't support view animations](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2011/11/android-40-graphics-and-animations.html) (See "Introducing TextureView").

--- UPDATE ----
Google fixed this issue on API 16: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4839

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue my solution was use a `ViewPager`, in one child I had a ListFragment, and in the another child I had a `FrameLayout` with two childs, an `ImageView` and the `SupportMapFragment`. After and before of do the switch I bring up to front the `ImageView`, then I use the method [snapshot(aCallback)](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#snapshot%28com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback%29) to put a `BitmapDrawable` in the `ImageView` with that you shouldn't have any problem.